# buckets are not getting created in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-partitioning

Look at the scripts, 
hive buckets are not creating after partitioning table,

```
step 1.
create table orders_bucket9
(order_id int,order_date string,order_customer_id int,order_status string) 
partitioned by (order_month string) 
clustered by (order_status) into 4 buckets
row format delimited
fields terminated by ',';

step 2.
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.enforce.buckting=true;
step 3.
insert into table orders_bucket9 partition(order_month) select                order_id,order_date,order_customer_id,order_status,substr(order_date,1,7) order_month from orders;
```

when i partitioned the table on bases of order_month the partitioning is getting created but buckting is not???

Comment: Can you check the output of what is shown when you do "describe formatted <table_name>"
You can find out on which column bucketing and partitioning is done.

Comment: only partition is showing on order_month...

Comment: Varun : Bucket info is shown in the **Bucket Columns** row. I executed your query and found out that the bucketing is done on the [order_status]    column.

Comment: Deepan: when I am loading data from insert command the buckets in hdfs location is not creating all the data is loading different set of partitioned table on order_month, but not buckets???